# How to extract NIC information using Get-AzureRmVM cmdlet

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I want to generate CSV file containing the VM names and the network interfaces that are attached to them. When I run the cmdlet, I see the following output in table format

```
ResourceGroupName Name Location VmSize  OsType NIC
```

When I try to select only the NIC object using the command `Get-AzureRmVM | select-object NIC` the output is blank.

Can anyone guide me on how to filter out the NIC names and the VM names ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because NIC not the project in `Get-AzureRmVm`, so we can't use `Get-AzureRmVM | select-object NIC` to get NIC name:

```
PS D:\testdata> get-azurermvm | gm


   TypeName: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachineList

Name                     MemberType Definition
----                     ---------- ----------
Equals                   Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode              Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType                  Method     type GetType()
ToPSVirtualMachine       Method     Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachine ToPSVirtualMachine()
ToString                 Method     string ToString()
AvailabilitySetReference Property   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.SubResource AvailabilitySetReference {...
DiagnosticsProfile       Property   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.DiagnosticsProfile DiagnosticsProfile ...
DisplayHint              Property   Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.DisplayHintType DisplayHint {get;set;}
Extensions               Property   System.Collections.Generic.IList[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.Virtu...
HardwareProfile          Property   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.HardwareProfile HardwareProfile {get;s...
Id                       Property   string Id {get;set;}
Identity                 Property   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.VirtualMachineIdentity Identity {get;s...
InstanceView             Property   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.VirtualMachineInstanceView InstanceVie...
LicenseType              Property   string LicenseType {get;set;}
Location                 Property   string Location {get;set;}
Name                     Property   string Name {get;set;}
NetworkProfile           Property   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.NetworkProfile NetworkProfile {get;set;}
OSProfile                Property   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.OSProfile OSProfile {get;set;}
Plan                     Property   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.Plan Plan {get;set;}
ProvisioningState        Property   string ProvisioningState {get;set;}
RequestId                Property   string RequestId {get;set;}
ResourceGroupName        Property   string ResourceGroupName {get;}
StatusCode               Property   System.Net.HttpStatusCode StatusCode {get;set;}
StorageProfile           Property   Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.StorageProfile StorageProfile {get;set;}
Tags                     Property   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary[string,string] Tags {get;set;}
Type                     Property   string Type {get;set;}
VmId                     Property   string VmId {get;set;}
```

> Can anyone guide me on how to filter out the NIC names and the VM
>   names ?

As a workaround, we can use this script to get the NIC name:

```
$a = get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName jasonvm -Name jasonvm
$b = $a.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.id -split "/"
$nic = $b[-1]
$nic
```

Then we can use `$nic` to get the information about NIC, like this:

```
Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nic -ResourceGroupName jasonvm
```